# Setting up SimpleSAMLphp as a SP for CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, simplesamlphp

I have to continue on an already existing CodeIgniter 3 application (not written by me) which contains multiple applications for different customers, the project structure looks a little like this:

- root/

  - applications/

    - customer1/

      - config/, controllers/, models/, views/, ...
      - **third_party/**

        - **SimpleSAMLphp/**

          - **config/, metadata/, www/, ...**
          - **lib/**

            - **_autoload.php**
    - customer2/
    - ...
  - assets/, bundle/, ...
  - customers/

    - customer1/

      - assets/, index.php, ...
    - customer2/
    - ...
  - system/
  - vendor/
  - composer/
  - autoload.php

Now for one of the applications I have to replace the ion_auth system with an SSO (setup as a Service Provider from their IdP metadata). I googled a lot and tought SimpleSAMLphp would be my best option.

But I am really struggling just even putting the SimpleSAMLphp SP API into my application and the [documentation](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-sp-api) isn't great.

-I "include_once" the third_party/SimpleSAMLphp/lib/_autoload.php file in the customers/customer1/index.php file (before require_once BASEPATH...)
-I modified third_party/SimpleSAMLphp/lib/_autoload.php so it finds the vendor/autoload.php file

I expect to be able to use the methods of the SimpleSAMLphp library but instead I get the following errors:

-If I follow the code in [this](https://www.webtrafficexchange.com/simplesamlphp-implementation-tutorial) guide:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple()**

-If use include APPPATH . 'third_party\SimpleSAMLphp\www\index.php in my controller just above the code from above tutorial:
**Fatal error: Class 'SimpleSAML\Error\Assertion' not found in**

What am I doing wrong in my setup?